# Does TensorFlow allow definition of variables with undefined size?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does TensorFlow allow definition of variables with undefined size? For example I can easily define a placeholder with `None` values in shape - this means that these values can be specified at run time, after the graph is built. *But shapes of variables must be supplied before construction of the graph.* Is the previous statement true? If it is, why is it so?

Comment: Are you talking about tensorflow Variables? As in these guys: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable

Comment: Yes, about them

Comment: Just curious, why do you need Variables of undefined size?

Comment: For example if i want to write a egression model with factor varibles. The number of factors can change from run to run.

Comment: You don't need to have a variable with a variable size for this, because in effect you have different models -- even though they share the same general architecture. Typically you would create them with the same function that takes the variable size as a parameter.

Comment: But this requires rebuilding the graph every time I call the function. This costs some time. But I can ask another question: does TF suite for building classical ML models with aim to run them fast? I mean models with computation time comparable with time needed to build graph.

Comment: I think graph construction time is usually small compared to anything else you are likely to do with your graph. Constructing a graph for a single computation is atypical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable shapes can actually be changed after constructing the graph.

Example:

```
value = tf.placeholder("float", [None])
x = tf.Variable(value, validate_shape=False)
with_assign_op = tf.assign(x, [1,2,3,4,5], validate_shape=False)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([x]), feed_dict={value: [1,2,3]})
print(sess.run(x)) # [ 1.  2.  3.]

sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([x]), feed_dict={value: [1,2,3,4]})
print(sess.run(x)) # [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]

sess.run(with_assign_op)
print(sess.run(x)) # [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#__init__) on `tf.Variable`.

The keyword argument `validate_shape`:

> If False, allows the variable to be initialized with a value of unknown shape. If True, the default, the shape of initial_value must be known.

So setting this to False would allow you to initialize the variable with a value of unknown shape.

Comment: Does this add any restrictions on the other parts of model?

Comment: You would probably have to be careful about what operations you call on the variable at different points in time. Personally, I don't know any reason why you would want to have a dynamically sized variable.